# What are hs_err_pid.log files generated when Tomcat crashes?

Tags: java, tomcat, crash, jvm

Are any specific settings required on the Java tab of Tomcat configuration tool in order to generate a `hs_err_pid.log` file?

What is the default location of the `hs_err_pid.log` file? Can this location be changed?

Answer (score 70):

A very **very** good document regarding this topic is [Troubleshooting Guide for Java](https://web.archive.org/web/20210915102559/https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/6hotspotvm.html) from (originally) Sun. See the chapter "Troubleshooting System Crashes" for information about `hs_err_pid*` Files.

See [Appendix C - Fatal Error Log](https://web.archive.org/web/20201025232140/https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/felog.html#gbwcy)

Per the guide, by default the file will be created in the working directory of the process if possible, or in the system temporary directory otherwise. A specific location can be chosen by passing in the `-XX:ErrorFile` product flag.  It says:

> If the -XX:ErrorFile= file flag is not specified, the system attempts to create the file in the working directory of the process. In the event that the file cannot be created in the working directory (insufficient space, permission problem, or other issue), the file is created in the temporary directory for the operating system.

Comment: so it's safe to delete these files? thanks for your help!

Comment: It is. (fixing stupid "comments must be at least 15 characters in length" limit)