# Debug for OpenJDK

Tags: debugging, java

Very often, the OpenJDK image compiled from modified source code will crash with the following error message:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000000000000, pid=1234, tid=4321
#
# JRE version: 7.0
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (21.0-b17 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x0000000000000000
#
# Core dump written. Default location:
    C:\Users\user62951413\workspace\JDKTestBuild\hs_err_pid1234.mdmp
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\user62951413\workspace\JDKTestBuildr\hs_err_pid1234.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

The hs_err_pidxxxx.log file isn't very helpful, and the minidump contains too much information. Are there easier ways to find out whats wrong with the compiled JDK?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019596/can-anybody-tell-me-details-about-hs-err-pid-log-file-generated-when-tomcat-cras