# Java(TM) platform SE binary has stopped working error message while detecting external hardware connectivity in Swing application

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

This is quite detailed so please bear with me.

I am connecting a hardware device to my Swing application (Yes, Swing). This device is a camera for iris biometric data capture.

In my project, I have a device monitor class that listens for connections or disconnections from this device. This is implemented like this in the class `DeviceMonitorThread` which extends `Thread`

```
private static boolean monitorDevices = true;    
private boolean irisScannerConnectionStatus = false;
...

private synchronized boolean checkIrisScannerConnectivity() {
    logger.debug(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Checking iris scanner connectivity...");
    Controller.deviceMonitorIrisScannerOn = true;

    if (Controller.irisScannerOn) {
        logger.debug(">>>>>>>>>>>>> Iris camera is connected so device monitor thread was skipped...");
        Controller.deviceMonitorIrisScannerOn = false;
        return true;
    }

    try {
        if (Controller.iIrisCam == null) {
            Controller.iIrisCam = new IrisCamJNI();
        }

        Controller.iIrisCam.connectToCameraIndex(0);
        irisScannerConnectionStatus = Controller.iIrisCam.isCameraConnected();
        logger.debug(irisScannerConnectionStatus ? ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Iris Scanner is connected" : "Iris scanner is not connected");
        if (irisScannerConnectionStatus) {
            try {
                logger.debug(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>.Disconnecting iriscam");
                Controller.iIrisCam.disconnect();                    
            } catch (IrisCamException irisCamException) {
                logger.error("[Error]", irisCamException);
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                logger.error("ERROR ", exception);
            } catch (Error error) {
                logger.error("Error", error);
                throw new Error(error);
            }
            return true;
        }

    } catch (IrisCamException exception) {
        logger.error(">>>>>>>>>> Error initializing IrisCam object...........", exception);
    }

    return false;

}
```

This is the `run()` method:

```
@SuppressWarnings("SleepWhileInLoop")
@Override
public void run() {

    while (monitorDevices) {

        if (!monitorDevices) {
            break;
        }

        try {
            logger.debug(">>>>>>>>>>>>>About to check irisScannerConnectivity()...");
            boolean newIrisScannerConnectionStatus = checkIrisScannerConnectivity();
            logger.debug(">>>>>>>>newIrisScannerConnectionStatus = " + newIrisScannerConnectionStatus);
            if (newIrisScannerConnectionStatus != irisScannerConnectionStatus) {
                irisScannerConnectionStatus = newIrisScannerConnectionStatus;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }        

        notifyListeners();
        try {
            if (!monitorDevices) {
                break;
            }
            Thread.sleep(THREAD_SLEEP_INTERVAL);
            if (systemExited) {
                monitorDevices = false;
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            logger.error("Thread Interrutped: ", e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Exception in device monitor thread");
        }

    }

}
```

`iIrisCam` and the other booleans are declared in the Controller class as thus:

```
   public static IIrisCam iIrisCam;
   public static boolean irisScannerOn, deviceMonitorIrisScannerOn = false;
```

Now, when I run this app. I have to keep my fingers crossed because this crash DOESN'T ALWAYS happen. It crashes now, and the next time I am able to capture the images or it crashes a couple of times in a row and so on.

When It does crash, this is the error message I get:

[image]

With the all mighty

[image]

This project uses a lot of `.dll` files (placed in the `System32` and `sysWOW64` folders) from the IIrisCam SDK.

I have done lots of logging but the cause of this error never seems to be caught. My guess is this has to do with memory being used and not released.
I'll provide more information for anyone willing to help.

if it's of any relevance, I am using a 64bits windows 10 computer, while the IIrisCam sdk uses a lot of 32bit stuff.

**Edit**

This is what the `run.xml` file referenced in the error message looks like:

```
<project name="{0} (run)" default="run" basedir=".">
<target name="run">        
    <translate-classpath classpath="${classpath}" targetProperty="classpath-translated" />
    <property name="run.jvmargs" value="" />
    <property name="work.dir" value="${basedir}"/>
    <property name="application.args" value="" />
    <property name="java.failonerror" value="true"/>
    <java classpath="${classpath-translated}" classname="${classname}" dir="${work.dir}" jvm="${platform.java}" fork="true" failonerror="${java.failonerror}">
        <jvmarg value="-Dfile.encoding=${encoding}"/>
        <redirector inputencoding="${encoding}" outputencoding="${encoding}" errorencoding="${encoding}"/>
        <jvmarg line="${run.jvmargs}" />
        <arg line="${application.args}" />
        <syspropertyset>
            <propertyref prefix="run-sys-prop."/>
            <mapper from="run-sys-prop.*" to="*" type="glob"/>
        </syspropertyset>
    </java>
</target>
```

Comment: If you are sending any data from Java to native code, check that all objects are not null before assigning them. And, Swing rocks!!! :)

Comment: If your Java crashes inside native stack frames, it often produces a crash dump file in your program's working directory called `hs_err`. Do you have any of these files? If you're using native libraries, you can find some useful info in the `hs_err` file, e.g. what kind of fault, what instruction address it was executing, the native stack frame, etc. More info can be found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019596/can-anybody-tell-me-details-about-hs-err-pid-log-file-generated-when-tomcat-cras) and its related references about how to understand these files.

Comment: @RafaelGuillen Thanks. I am currently investigating this.The error doesn't seem to be from the iIrisCam object but from deep down somewhere in native code.

Comment: @Brian Searched for these files and I've got a handful of them. I'll get back here once I get something.