# The file "hs_err_pid1966.log" always occurs in my $Home directory on ubuntu18.04.3，who can help me？

Tags: java, ubuntu-18.04

I always have beed bothered by the file when I turn on my computer every time.I enjoy ubuntu18.04.3 except it.Who can help me?some screenshots display below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpK9s.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's a crash log, generated when a program dies.

Have you looked *in* the file? It'll tell you [about](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/felog-138657.html#gbmuz) the crash. With that information, you can hopefully identify the application that's messed up so you can either a) fix it or b) remove it.

This was the second result in google search for "java hs_err_pid":

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019596/can-anybody-tell-me-details-about-hs-err-pid-log-file-generated-when-tomcat-cras . It's more technical, but useful background info.
```